# delete selected video from SD card and gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, alert, delete-file

I created an imageviewer app. Its working fine but when I select a gridview item to delete it, it stops working. On selecting the item, delete button appears . On clicking the delete button ,an alert dialog appears asking for confirmation.I want the file to get deleted after cliking the YES button. But it does not happen. Instead it throws an *indexoutofbounds* exception. How can I delete selected file succesfully ?

**PhotosActivity.java**

```
import static com.example.dell_1.myapp3.ImageViewer.ImageGallery.al_images;

public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int int_position;
    private GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_images, int_position);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("folderPosition", int_position);
                i.putExtra("abc", abc);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                for (int j = 0; j < parent.getChildCount(); j++)
                    parent.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                // change the background color of the selected element
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotosActivity.this);
                                builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete it ?");
                                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                        "Yes",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                File file = new File( al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position));
                                                file.delete();
                                               al_menu.remove(position);
                                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            }
                                        });

                                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                        "No",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                alert11.show();
                            }
                        });
                return true;
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**GridViewAdapter.java**:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model_images> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    int int_position;


    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu,int int_position) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu = al_menu;
        this.context = context;
        this.int_position = int_position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() + "");
        return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() > 0) {
            return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
            viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_foldern.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
        ImageView iv_image;

    }
}
```

**LOGCAT :**

```
10-15 11:38:03.449 31844-31844/com.example.dell_1.Myapp3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.dell_1.Myapp3, PID: 31844
                                                                           java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                               at com.example.dell_1.myapp3.ImageViewer.PhotosActivity$2$1$1.onClick(PhotosActivity.java:87)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0):

what is **al_images** ??

you have not initialized **al_images**

Comment: I initialized it in another class, imported it here using  'import static com.example.dell_1.myapp3.ImageViewer.ImageGallery.al_images;' . I have updated the code .

Comment: check this part **String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);**
you may have not initialized ArrayList returned by this method **getAl_imagepath()**

Comment: your LOGCAT says it has no elements

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the item for the Grid, you should also have to notify the grid adapter of the change in the data set.

1. Delete the item from the data set.
2. Notify the Grid Adapter of the change in data set.

The above behavior needs to be defined in the Adapter's getView() method. While populating the elements after the (if else) block. You should set a tag with every view in order to correctly identify which item you want to delete. Use

```
ViewHolder.deleteButton.setTag(position);
```

In this case param will be your delete button, so that after clicking the button, you will know the item whose button is clicked and perform the following function in the getView() method.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Gets the index of the item to delete
        Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();

        // Use the above index to delete item from data set
        // Delete your item here
        //For e.g: notes.remove(index.intValue());

        // Must call this after deletion from the data set
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```